# How to allocate memory to a pointer to pointer in a function

Tags: c

I want to allocate memory for char* pointer in a char** pointer while doing it in a function, what am I doing wrong?

```
int main(void)
{
    char** ar = NULL;

    inti(&ar);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
void inti(char*** x)
{

    *x = (char**)calloc(sizeof(char*), 4);
}
```

and I want to send on of the cell in x to another function that will calloc there memory for an array of chars how can I do the follow up function?

Comment: What makes you think it's wrong? Are you getting an error?

Comment: Looks fine to me. Except that `(char**)` is redundant. What's the problem you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

May I recommend cutting out the middle man and doing the following? (Also, your calloc() args are backwards I believe).

```c
char** inti() {
    char** c = calloc(4, sizeof(char*))

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        c[i] = malloc(/* length of string */);
    }

    return c;
}

int main(void) {
    char** ptrptr = inti();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! for your response:)
And If I would like to use another function to set the c[i] how would you recommend me to do it?

Comment: Make a function ```followup(char** ptr)``` and copy paste the loop into it.

Comment: @id0SI It's customary to answer questions you get to your post.